# My spring application boot will not stop runing

Tags: java, spring

when I start my spring app it will not stop even when I close it
the main is:

```
 ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx=  SpringApplication.run(CouponProjectSpringApplication.class, args);
 System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
 ctx.close();
```

it wouldn't print neither he will stop

the git link is :[https://github.com/torchkatannatlie/Coupon-Project.git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIZXf.png)
I will  appreciate your help

[in the picture, you will see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIZXf.png)

Comment: You can always do System.exit(0). :^) joke

Comment: You need to include the output (1) in your question (2) as text, but the code you posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

You code works right, but on your screenshot I don't see line like:
`Started CouponProjectSpringApplication in 1.935 seconds (JVM running for 2.349)`
From my point of view, you application didn't start, I mean command `SpringApplication.run(CouponProjectSpringApplication.class, args);` was not executed, or you have issue during startup process, please attach full application log.